# Why is rm -r the same as rm -R?

Tags: rm, options

If you look in the [`rm` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/rm.1.html) you see that `rm -r`, `rm -R`, and `rm --recursive` are all the same.

```
-r, -R, --recursive
      remove directories and their contents recursively
```

When using options, I'm used to them being case sensitive where quite often a different case will have a (often completely different) purpose. This can even be seen in `rm` where `rm -i` is equivalent to `rm --interactive=always` and `rm -I` is equivalent to `rm --interactive=once`.

Are there any historical reasons for both the `-r` and `-R` options being the same as `--recursive`? Are there any reasons for using one over the other (such as compatibility across systems)?

Comment: per posix [docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/rm.html): _the_ `-r` _option is historical practice on all known systems. The synonym_ `-R` _option is provided for consistency with the other utilities..._

Comment: @don_crissti That makes sense, and I thought the "other utility" might be `cp` until I realized that `cp -r` and `cp -R` at one point [were actually different](https://github.com/goj/coreutils/commit/246e147a6a6b9d460376f7f7889191d13652456e), though that doesn't explain why `cp -r` was removed [from the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html) (but not implementations), while `rm` wasn't affected.

Comment: Well, utilities like `ls`, `chmod` and `chown` use `-R` (not `-r`) for `--recursive`.  Also, (usually) the reasons are hidden in various changelogs/commits.